# Reporting on SQL statement success/fail with .sql file and SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm the same guy that asked:

[BEGIN/END and CREATE Table in single .sql file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397449/begin-end-and-create-table-in-single-sql-file)

Anyhow, we have a several .sql scripts we're executing via SQL*Plus.

These scripts are used for creating tables, synonyms, indexes, views etc.

A single .sql file will usually have several CREATE statements inside them.

What we're looking for is a way to report pass/fail for each CREATE statement, as well as an error message if it failed.

```
Create table foo: Pass
Create index bar: Fail - Reason...
Create synonym foo_1: Pass etc.
```

Currently, we can parse the SQL*Plus output, however, this has a lot of extraneous stuff in it, and parsing a logfile like this isn't the most robust approach.

Is there a better way to programmatically check on the return status of each SQL statement via SQL*Plus, and the error message, if any? Is that something achievable with SQL*Plus?

Or do I need to write a wrapper of some sort (Bash, Python etc.)? Or handle this all via another way?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I don't like embedding logic into DDL scripts, unless absolutely needed
(the script can easily become overly complicated, and its action less predictable)

I prefer to scan the script output for errors e.g: grep for the string  ORA-

Then check there are no invalid objects in the schema

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue with the SQL script when an error occurs, then you should create your tables and indices from within a PL/SQL block since PL/SQL has a decent exception handling:

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE XY ( ... )';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Creating table XY failed: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

If you want to end the current SQL script when an error occurs, you can use the following SQL*Plus command and do the error handling in the script that called SQL*plus:

```
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode
```